# CLion saying a C++ class function doesn't exist when it does

Tags: c++, clion

I have a class called `Computer` and in it has a function called `setPos`. Clion refuses to acknowledge the existence of `getPos` or any other function I put in there except for the constructor.

snippet from main.cpp

```
    Computer gateway = Computer::Computer("Gateway");
    gateway.setPos(&neighbor,&supermarket, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Computer.hpp

```
class Computer
{
public:
    Computer::Computer(string name);
    void Computer::setPos(Computer* up, Computer* right, Computer* down, Computer * left);
    string Computer::getName();

    string name;

    Computer* up = nullptr;
    Computer* down = nullptr;
    Computer* right = nullptr;
    Computer* left = nullptr;
};
```

Computer.cpp

```
#include "Computer.hpp"

Computer::Computer(int level, bool hidden, string name, int money)
{
    this->name = name;
}

void Computer::setPos(Computer* up, Computer* right, Computer* down, Computer * left)
{
    this->up = up;
    this->down = down;
    this->right = right;
    this->left = left;
}

string Computer::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}
```

[image]

The function exists, my code works as intended, but CLion says it doesn't exist. How can I remedy this problem inside the IDE

Comment: Your code [doesn't look valid](https://godbolt.org/g/BW9cuf).

Comment: Get rid of the `Computer::` in the header file you dont need to tell it what class it belongs to. It is obvious it is a part of Computer

Comment: Thank you @JackVanier that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JackVanier said, removing the class name from the declaration in the header file fixed the issue.